# how to print user_id using the devise gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I currently trying to do something like this in the applicaiton.html.erb

```
<h1> <% print "Customer id #{current_user}"%> </h1>
```

but I get nothing. the 'Customer id' is not being printed either. What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks for your time

Comment: Using erb, then `<h1><%= "Customer id #{current_user.id}"%></h1>`

Comment: @SebastianPalma yes that worked thatnks so much. If u want post it as answer and I will choose it so that other might benefit from it too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're in a Rails view, using erb, then print or puts are not needed.

The `<%= %>` allows you to render (print) the expression that's contained inside, while `<% %>` allows you to create Ruby logic without rendering it, the same way `<%# %>` works for comments, so you could do:

```
<h1>
  <%= "Customer id #{current_user.id} "%>
</h1>
```

Or:

```
<h1>Customer id <%= current_user.id %></h1>
```

No need to concatenate, and in both cases accessing to the current_user id attribute, otherwise it'd return the whole User object.

Comment: thanks I need 6 minutes to choose it as anwer. Can u plesae answer this questoin too ? I am trying to do this `<h1><%= "User name:  #{User.select(:username).where(User.arel_table[:id].eq(1))}"%></h1>` but it doesn't work. The equivalent in SQL is `SELECT username 
FROM users
WHERE user.id = 1` Thanks

Comment: I don't know much about arel, but using active record you could do `<h1>
  Customer id <%= User.select(:id).find(1).id %>
</h1>`, note you should put `User.select(:id).find(1).id` in an instance variable in your controller, and then use it in the view, note also put the text outside the erb tags and then just print the logic. Also if you have more questions you can create a new detailed question in order any user can help you.

Comment: Thanks agian, I got it now.